# Depth of the reduced subfactor

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras, subfactors, planar-algebras

Suppose $N\subset M$ is a finite depth subfactor with $[M:N]<\infty$. Consider the reduced subfactor $pNp\subset pMp$ for some projection $p\in N$. How to calculate the depth of $pNp\subset pMp$ in terms of the depth of $N\subset M$? In particular, is it true that if $N\subset M$ is of depth 2, then $pNp\subset pMp$ will be also of depth 2? Of course, if $p$ is projection in $N^{\prime}\cap M$ the situation is easier and known. Any help will be appreciated.